# Creating a single element with fixed px height in flexbox column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I'm mixing Flexbox and Bootstrap3 to create a truly flexible layout.

However, I'm hitting a bit of a brick wall trying to keep a 'cell' in a flexbox layout at a predetermined px height:

```
+---------------+
|  +---------+  |
|  |    a    |  |
|  +---------+  |      a: should always be 200px high, never smaller or taller
|  +---------+  |
|  |         |  |
|  |    b    |  |     
|  |         |  |          
|  |---------|  |
|  |         |  |  
|  |    c    |  |    b and c: should share the rest of the space (100% - 200px) 
|  |         |  |               equally between them (50% / 50%)
|  +---------+  |
+---------------+
```

I've tried to set a to a div with :

```
#fixedcont {
    height: 300px;
}
```

I've created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/StephanTual/nu83c/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your HTML to include a class in the element that I think that you want to set to 200px (not fully clear)

```
<div class="full-height container">
    <div class="sectiona">
        <h4>Title for Section A</h4>
```

and have set the style to

```
.sectiona {
    flex-basis: 200px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

This seems to work

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nu83c/10/)

However, in the rest of the fiddle is not really clear what you are trying to get.

This that, at least in Chrome, you need to set all the flex properties :

```
.sectiona {
    flex-basis: 200px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nu83c/13/)

Comment: Thanks Vals, unfortunately this does not work. I've updated the fiddle to better explain what I'm trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/StephanTual/nu83c/12/

Comment: In short, section A should always be 200px high, while B&C share the remaining space equally.

Comment: YOu are right, in Chrome at least doesn't work, fixed now ! (I hope)